# IPhone: create view with text and images

Tags: iphone, image, text

I want create some view, and add dynamically  to it text and images
Somebody knows how I can to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broad question, but this should get you on the right path:  (Pop this into a viewcontroller)

```
-(void)addStuffToView{
    UIView* myView = [self view]; // get the view controller's view

    UIImageView* myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
    [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagefile.jpg"]];
    [myView addSubview:myImageView];
    [myImageView release];

    UILabel* myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,100,50)];
    myLabel.text = @"Some text here";
    [myView addSubview:myLabel];
    [myLabel release];
}
```

Then, bind this method to your UIButton's `touchUpInside` event using Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks, but i want add it on some event, for example on button click

Comment: It's customary to upvote or accept answers which solve your problem or provide help in some way.

Comment: Really?  Interesting.  And I suppose the "accept" isn't available for another like ten minutes.  Well, try out the code and let me know how it works out for you.  You should also look into using Navigation Views.

Comment: Ok, what do you think about UIWebView, maybe it will better way?